# Calculate Data Rate

Tags: networking

The question is:

> What data rate is needed to transmit an uncompressed 4" x 6" photograph every second with a resolution of 1200 dots per inch and 24 bits per dot (pixel)?

My Solution was 4*6*1200*24 which is equal to 691,200 bps but it doesn't match with any of the option given for the problem. The options are:
a) 691200 kb/s
b) 28.8 kb/s
c) 28.8 kbits
d) 8.29 Mb/s
e) 829 Mb/s

What wrong am I doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct answer is e)

Taking into account both dimension.
Calculation is as follows:
4 x 1200 x 6 x 1200 x 24 = 829440000 b/s => Choice 829 Mb/s

Answer (score 1):

your math is wrong. because this is question from Stanford networking i do not want to provide right answer. But here is the tip: try your calculation for 1x1 picture :). so 1x1x1200 is definitely not correct :), get to the second dimension :)

Answer (score 0):

I think they're talking about the minimum required to transmit it. So, just work out each of those speeds in bits per second and choose the minimum that is greater than 691,000 bps.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong,
The answer could be option A in the case either the question or the optional answer is wrong. Even if you calculate 691200/(1024²) (which should be the answer in mb/s) you get an answer near 0.66.
So either I am wrong or the question is wrong. I guess the second.

Comment: Basic dimensional analysis tells that this approach is wrong. `inch*inch*(dots/inch)*bits/dot = inch-bits` and not `bits` as required.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is 829.44mbps  (closest option is e).
4*1200*6*1200 gives the total number of dpi.
Multiplying further by 24 gives the total number of bits.